# Ubuntu 20.04 battery issue

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery

My computer couldn't charge full. It changed at least one night and it didn't charge anything. And it losed 1% battery.

I am using DELL ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

[image: picture]

I installed then acpi with apt to solve this problem.

input:

```
acpi -b
```

output:

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 93%
```

can someone solve this problem and could it die with 0% battery?

UPDATE:

input:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

output:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               LGC-LGC3.6
  model:                DELL G95J55B
  serial:               43336
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 16 Nov 2020 08:03:46 CET (30 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              40.441 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         43.105 Wh
    energy-full-design:  53.28 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0135863 W
    voltage:             8.58 V
    percentage:          93%
    capacity:            80.9028%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

Comment: It happend twice but I forgot it how it was solved.

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question and add details about laptop, like manufacture, specif model, maybe if you can find battery model name etc. Also please can you find file ```/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/``` and provide output of : ```$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0```

Comment: `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:

```
sudo shutdown now
```

This shutdowns the computer but this was the only solution i know.
If you have a better answer then please post an answer to this question.
After a few seconds you should start the computer again and see what happends next.

Comment: check the battery after shutdown and you open the computer with `acpi -b`